# Perform Update in sql query loop

Tags: sql, loops, sql-update, sybase

I am trying to update ColumnA in TableA based on TableB. Below is the result set i need to loop through to update TableA.

```
SELECT TableB.ColumnA, 
       TableB.ColumnB 
  FROM TableA, TableB 
 WHERE TableA.ColumnA =NULL 
   AND TableB.ColumnB = TableA.ColumnB 
   AND TableB.ColumnC =true;
```

CoulmnA in both tables are same type and data
ColumnB in both tables are same type and data.

What i am unable to do is loop through the result set and update TableA in a similar fasion written below:

for each row in Result set above.

```
UPDATE TableA 
   SET ColumnA =  ResultSet.ColumnA  
 WHERE TableA.ColumnB = ResultSet.ColumnB;
```

Comment: Do you have to loop?  You can't just use the query you've written as the base for your update and do it all at once?

Comment: I am not sure how? could you kindly explain? thanks

Comment: both of your queries have the same `where` part: `tableA.ColumnB = ResultSet.ColumnB` (in result set ColumnB=TableB.ColumnB); so you can simply where update query with `where` statement from your first query

Comment: I mean, solution has to be something like `UPDATE A,B
SET A.ColumnA = B.ColumnA
WHERE A.ColumnA = NULL AND B.ColumnB = A.ColumnB AND B.ColumnC = true;`
I did't check, but it should work;

Comment: it is throwing buch of syntax errors for the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would write it in SQl Server and looking at the sybase syntax, it looks as if it might work as well.

```
UPDATE A     
SET ColumnA = B.ColumnB  
--SELECT   ColumnA , B.ColumnB  
FROM tableA A 
JOIN TableB B  
ON  B.ColumnB = A.ColumnB            
WHERE A.ColumnA = NULL AND B.ColumnC =true;
```

Note I put the comment line in so that you can see the actual values you would get to make sure the update is correct before you run it. It also show how to turn a select statement into an update.

Comment: Note I removed the implicit joins, they area SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are using the pairs generated by your query for update purposes.  You want the first value to turn into the second value.

The exact syntax depends on the version of SQL you are using.  Here is an example with SQL Server:

```
with toupdate as (SELECT TableB.ColumnA, TableB.ColumnB
                  from TableA join TableB
                       TableB.ColumnB = TableA.ColumnB
                  where TableA.ColumnA = NULL AND TableB.ColumnC =true
                 )
update tableA
    set TableA.ColumnA = toupdate.ColumnB
    from toupdate
    where toupdate.ColumnA = tableA.columnA
```

Without a "with" statement, you might try:

```
update tableA
    set TableA.ColumnA = toupdate.ColumnB
    from (SELECT TableB.ColumnA, TableB.ColumnB
          from TableA join TableB
               TableB.ColumnB = TableA.ColumnB
           where TableA.ColumnA = NULL AND TableB.ColumnC =true
          ) toupdate
    where toupdate.ColumnA = tableA.columnA
```

Comment: sorry i am usin sybase not sql server. thank you for the reply. I am looking for somethign similar to Sybase

Comment: Sybase is very similar SQL server, the logic should be mostly the same - give this a try.

Comment: I tried the above logic and says syntax problem ,  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
 Msg: 156, Level: 15, State: 2
 Server: SYBASEN20, Line: 1

Comment: You could try doing a JOIN to the subquery rather than having it in the WITH clause. `UPDATE tableA set ... from ( .. subquery .. ) as toupdate where ...`

Comment: sorry it is throwing syntax errors at keyword 'AS' dont understand where to put it. i tried to change the location in to couple of places and still doesnt work. :)